# Do you need to know a lot of (regular?) graph theory to get into spectral graph theory?

Tags: reference-request, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Do you need to know a lot of (regular?) graph theory to get into spectral graph theory?

What are the prerequisites?

Comment: Try to follow the hard way: start reading Chung-Spectral Graph Theory and go back to Chartrand-Graphs and Dipgraphs when you find something obscure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jack D'Aurizio. If you think you know enough Graph Theory to understand Spectral Graph Theory, grab a Spectral Graph Theory book and start reading it. (My suggestions: Read either Spectral Graph Theory by Fan R. K. Chung, or Graph Spectra by Miegham) If you dont know a graph theory concept mentioned, search it up and learn it. Here's some "prerequisites" I think you would need to know for Spectral Graph Theory. 
-High Knowledge of Polyomials
-Eigenvector Values for Matrices
-Adjacency Matrices
-Lapacian Matrices (Basic knowledge)
-Graph Variance and Invariance

Good Luck with Spectral Graph Theory

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Did this answer your question?